# Pandas: Get value of mutliple sorting/grouping query

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using using Python 2.6 (company requirement) and Pandas 13.0.

I try to get the values from a DataFrame that match several criteria:

- Get the first and last element of a column where values are grouped together,
- And get the values multiple of x in another column.

Here is an example to illustrate:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'A' : [0.00, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.28,  0.30,  0.35,  0.43,  0.47,    0.5],
    'B' : [   1,    1,    1,    2,    2,     2,     3,     3,     3,      3],
    'C' : ['no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'],
})

df.set_index(df['A'], inplace=True)
```

The DataFrame gives:

```
in: print df

out:
     A     B   C
A                 
0.00  0.00  1   no
0.10  0.10  1   no
0.15  0.15  1   no
0.20  0.20  2   no
0.28  0.28  2  yes
0.30  0.30  2  yes
0.35  0.35  3  yes
0.43  0.43  3  yes
0.47  0.47  3  yes
0.50  0.50  3  yes
```

I would like to get the following values from the filter:

- Group the df by the column B and get the first and last element of each identical value in this group.
- Group the df by the column C and get the first and last element of each identical value in this group.
- Get also the value that are a multiple of 0.1 in column A

So:

```
     A     B   C
A                 
0.00  0.00  1   no
0.10  0.10  1   no
0.20  0.20  2   no
0.28  0.28  2  yes
0.30  0.30  2  yes
0.35  0.35  3  yes
0.50  0.50  3  yes
```

I don't know how to get this results in an easy way (avoiding loops).
Does someone has any idea?

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: This is two questions! To get the best help, I'd consider splitting it out into two separate questions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I try to achieve this in one time as it's this result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on python 2.7 and pandas 0.14, but I am almost sure this should be identical for your environment. Using your example data frame:

- Group the df by the column B and get the first and last element of each identical value in this group.

  ```
  df.groupby('B').head(1)
  df.groupby('B').last()
  ```
- Group the df by the column C and get the first and last element of each identical value in this group: Use the same snippets as above, but replacing 'B' for 'C'
- Get also the value that are a multiple of 0.1 in column A

  ```
  df[df.A % 0.1 == 0]
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I can't manage to combine the two first groupby statement and get back the filtered values with the index A. Any idea how to achieve this?